# Algebra:Linear Equations in one Variable

Tags: linear-algebra

I study in 9th standard. I'm dealing with a word problem.

> The tens digit of a two digit number exceeds its unit digit by $4$. If the
>   tens digit and units digit are in the ratio $3:1$, find the number.

Comment: If $t$ stands for tens and $u$ for units, then the ratio could be written as $t÷u=3÷1$ How could you describe the first statement in terms of algebra?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint, and see if you can get the solution.
Call the tens digit $t$ and the units digit $u$. Then you know that either have to be $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,$. The two hints you have are:

> The tens digit exceeds the unit digit by 4.

That is $t = 4+u$.

> Tens digit and units digit are in the ratio 3:1.

That is $t =3u$.

Can you try solving from here?

Answer (score 1):

If you just have to do it quickly :

you know that the tens and the units digit ratio, so try some digit :

1 and 3, it doesn't exceed it by 4

2 and 6, yes it does.

However, I think you want to know how does this work mathematically :
so you know that the number is : `t*10 + u`

and that `t = 3 * u`, and `t = u + 4`

you can now find `t` :

```
t = 3 * (t - 4)
```

find `u` and your 2 digit number

Answer (score 0):

Introduce symbols and express the given information as equation connecting  these symbols.

Let $t$ be the 10's digit, and $u$ be the unit digit.

First info is $t= u+4$, and the second info is $t=3u$. See if you can solve these two equations and get $t$ and $u$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

Write the two digit number as $10d+u$ where $d$ is the decimal digit and $u$ is the unit digit, then the conditions says
$$d=u+4$$
$$\frac{d}{u}=\frac{3}{1}$$